# Real Time Candle stick chart using javafx (and no jfreechart )

Tags: javafx-2, finance, candlestick-chart

I want to make a candlestick chart which reads stream of data and then plot it (so it will be plotting either as data comes or after certain period it will update the previous plot).

I do not want to use any third party software as Jfree chart want it to be build from javafx directly.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Edit :

Can anyone tell me how stage.show() works like which class which method it involke.

Answer (score 7):

The Ensemble application includes a candlestick chart implementation for JavaFX.

Download the sample [Ensemble (Java 7) source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html) or the [Ensemble (Java 8) source](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) from Oracle.

Ensemble is [Oracle BSD licensed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/oraclebsd-1603217.txt), so you are free to use it as you wish.

[image]

Comment: I have this code and need some help to understand some part of it

I am not getting what is candlewidth ??
and hence update function in Class candle

Am new to javafx so could you elaborate

Comment: The Candlestick implementation from Ensemble is an advanced chart, it is completely unsuitable for use by somebody new to JavaFX.  Get a lot more experience with the basics of JavaFX before you try something like this.

Comment: I have some basic knowledge of javafx and its chart library,

But I really need to work on CandleStick chart
I can catch things fast(I guess so)
so any little help will be really appreciated

Comment: Ok I need to ask few things as I have gone throw complete code
how setdata calls _seriesAdded()_ function and how _updateAxisRange()_ is called before primaryStage.show();

Also what modification do I need to make if I want it to draw graph of a stream of data let say drawing a new candle every 5 minutes...

Thank you :)

Also it will be very helpful if you can explain **update()** and **updateStyleClasses()** function in 'class candle'

Comment: Edit your question to detail what you have tried so far and add your clarification questions in there so that anybody can understand your full question and add their own answer if they wish.

Comment: ok so I was able to do something I want to thanks to your advuces.
I need one more help
now am able to plot new candles but am having some difficulty in adjusting view of my chart, earlier I was setting xaxis in its contructor but I want it to be dynamically changed... so for that I left field blanck (so default constructor is called)
and its auto adjusting axis acc. to data, but it is making candle looker much more wider than they should be , they are overlapping.
any suggestion for handling this.

Answer (score 5):

In case it may help, I have extracted from [Ensemble](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html) source code a minimal code for AdvCandleStickChart: https://gist.github.com/Nicolas56/e02b29431b820d7c8c218c804f0269b0
There are only two files: .java and .css, which form together a stand-alone application

[image]

Comment: I got this working with the provided sample data. However, when using real data I run into problems. I use a database with daily OHLC bars. This only works nicely if the oldest date and newest date are within the same month. Otherwise blank areas result in the chart (e.g. from 20200131 to 20200201). Modifying the X axis from a `NumberAxis` to `CategoryAxis` creates all kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the ensemble example myself and customized. It does not perform well over 1000 bars.  At least when your moving the 1000 bars and figure that out.  Which is a huge shock since I wrote the same thing in swing a while ago with stellar performance.

I would recommend rolling your own in fx.